# Wildcard domain redirect to www results in www.www.domain.com

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect

I'm trying to configure OpenResty (nginx) to redirect any non www domain to www. one

but the thing that i'm acheiving is this : www.www.domain.com

eh?

here are my server blocks

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  ^$http_host$;
    return       301 http://www.$http_host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  ~^(www.)$$http_host;

    location = / {
        content_by_lua '
            ngx.say("Host: ", ngx.req.get_headers()["Host"])
        ';
    }
}
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some trial and error , here is how i fixed it :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  $http_host;
    return       301 http://www.$http_host$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.*;

    location = / {
        content_by_lua '
            ngx.say("Host: ", ngx.req.get_headers()["Host"])
        ';
    }
}
```